# How can i create a chain of trust in Go?

Tags: go, keychain

So for a long while i have been trying to create a chain of trust in Go.
I used this code to create the certificate https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go
But if i set the isCA to false the certificate file in the browser will be empty and my browser will display an error saying: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER. How can i specify where it should check the certificate?
I looked at alot of examples but still don’t really understand how it should work. I tried using my own generated server CA and pasted a random intermediate CA under it but it doesn’t know where to check. I know it will deny the certificate, but i’m just trying to understand how the chain works in Go. I don’t know how to use a chain certificate in Go should i use the issuer in template or subject or aren’t those important etc. Does anyone have a example or could point me in the right direction? Thanks.

This is what i am trying to achieve (doesn’t matter if the rootCA is self signed it’s just for testing purposes)
[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxmJ1.png)

Comment: Yes, if you want a cert to be a CA, it's needs to have the `CA` flag and `KeyUsageCertSign`, so if you turn that off it worn't work like you say. What problem are you having exactly? Please create an [mcve] that explains your problem.

Comment: Well instead of the chain i want to get like in google i get a single blank line instead. The code i use is the same as i have linked above. However i get a blank line when i set the ca to false. And i can't find out why.

Comment: please take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643048/signing-certificate-request-with-certificate-authority